# Taylor series for the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-5)(z-7)}$ on a disc centered at point $z_0=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, laurent-series

I started by expressing the function as sum of two fractions using partial fraction decomposition to get $\frac{-1}{2(z-5)} + \frac{1}{2(z-7)}$

However I could only then end up writing that as the sum of two power series :

$$\frac{1}{10} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{3^n} - \frac{1}{14} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{7^n}$$ and I'm unsure how to write this in the form of a Taylor series.

Comment: Hint: $z-5=(z-3)-2$ and $z-7=(z-3)-4$.

Comment: Your MathJax coding technique definitely needs some work.  See my edits. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are looking to construct the series around $z_0 = 3$, we could have $\lvert z - 3\rvert < 1$ or $\lvert z - 3\rvert > 1$ which would be the series inside and outside a disc of radius one. In the first case, 
\begin{align}
\frac{1/2}{z - 3 - 4} - \frac{1/2}{z - 3 - 2}&= \frac{-1/8}{1 - (z-3)/4} + \frac{1/4}{1-(z-3)/2}\\
&= -1/8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{z-3}{4}\Bigr)^n+1/4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{z-3}{2}\Bigr)^n\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\biggl[\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\biggr](z-3)^n
\end{align}
This was due to the definition of a geometric series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}
$$
for $\lvert r\rvert < 1$.

If we want a power series convergent outside the disc, $\lvert z - 3\rvert > 1\iff 1/\lvert z -3\rvert < 1$.
$$
\frac{1}{2(z - 3)}\frac{1}{1 - 4/(z-3)} - \frac{1}{2(z-3)}\frac{1}{1 - 2/(z-3)}
$$
which leads to a Laurent series. What do you get for the Laurent series convergent outside of the disc?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2(z-3)}$ ($\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{z-3}\right)^n$ - $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{z-3}\right)^n$) ?

Comment: @rb20 yes and that series is for $\lvert z-3\rvert > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For example,
$$
\frac{1}{z-7} = \frac{1}{(z-3)-4} = -\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{1-(z-3)/4} = -\frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z-3}{4}\right)^i.
$$

Comment: Okay I can see how this is useful, so we can write the function as $\frac {1}{4}$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z-3}{2}\right)^n$ $\frac{1}{8}$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z-3}{4}\right)^n$ ? but I still don't see how that helps